# GitHub Release Workflow Is Not Working and Is No Longer Running

Tags: github-actions, goreleaser, terraform-registry

I am making a custom terraform provider for my organization.
I was following the instructions here:

- https://www.terraform.io/registry/providers/publishing?_ga=2.233394398.119722977.1642457969-242172196.1631994131

In the section where it mentions to set up a GitHub Action by copying over the following into my workflows directory:

- GitHub Actions workflow from the terraform-provider-scaffolding repository (https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-scaffolding/blob/main/.github/workflows/release.yml)

Unfortunately doing so seems to have caused the `release` workflow to no longer work and run. As a result, I was hoping I might get some overall insights into this as I am trying to hook it up to terraform registry and it's not letting me publish it because of a mal-release configuration.

Here is the repo:

- https://github.com/Richard-Barrett/terraform-provider-mirantis

Here is the code that I am using for `release.yml` in my existing `workflows`:

```sh
# This GitHub action can publish assets for release when a tag is created.
# Currently its setup to run on any tag that matches the pattern "v*" (ie. v0.1.0).
#
# This uses an action (hashicorp/ghaction-import-gpg) that assumes you set your 
# private key in the `GPG_PRIVATE_KEY` secret and passphrase in the `PASSPHRASE`
# secret. If you would rather own your own GPG handling, please fork this action
# or use an alternative one for key handling.
#
# You will need to pass the `--batch` flag to `gpg` in your signing step 
# in `goreleaser` to indicate this is being used in a non-interactive mode.
#
name: release
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'v*'
jobs:
  goreleaser:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      -
        name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.4.0
      -
        name: Unshallow
        run: git fetch --prune --unshallow
      -
        name: Set up Go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v2
        with:
          go-version: 1.17
      -
        name: Import GPG key
        id: import_gpg
        uses: hashicorp/ghaction-import-gpg@v2.1.0
        env:
          # These secrets will need to be configured for the repository:
          GPG_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.GPG_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          PASSPHRASE: ${{ secrets.PASSPHRASE }}
      -
        name: Run GoReleaser
        uses: goreleaser/goreleaser-action@v2.8.0
        with:
          version: latest
          args: release --rm-dist
        env:
          GPG_FINGERPRINT: ${{ steps.import_gpg.outputs.fingerprint }}
          # GitHub sets this automatically
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

I think it may be the way I am auto-tagging in my repo as well, here is what I am using within my `tag.yml`:

```sh
name: 'tag'
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  tag:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: 'Checkout'
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.4.0
      - name: 'Tag'
        uses: anothrNick/github-tag-action@1.36.0
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Also, the `tag` workflow wasn't working at first, but now is, but my release status is just showing `no status`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much chagrin and heartache, I found out why it wasn't working.
I didn't specify the Branch on which the action was to be triggered:

Answer:

- https://github.com/Richard-Barrett/terraform-provider-mirantis/commit/62a1fb003aee118e133dd22ce79dd488798214e1

The overall change was adding that to the `release.yml`.
The `tag.yml` is fine.

As a result, here was the overall change:

```sh
name: 'release'
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    tags:
      - 'v*'
jobs:
```

And the final release file looked like this:

```
# This GitHub action can publish assets for release when a tag is created.
# Currently its setup to run on any tag that matches the pattern "v*" (ie. v0.1.0).
#
# This uses an action (hashicorp/ghaction-import-gpg) that assumes you set your 
# private key in the `GPG_PRIVATE_KEY` secret and passphrase in the `PASSPHRASE`
# secret. If you would rather own your own GPG handling, please fork this action
# or use an alternative one for key handling.
#
# You will need to pass the `--batch` flag to `gpg` in your signing step 
# in `goreleaser` to indicate this is being used in a non-interactive mode.
#
name: 'release'
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    tags:
      - 'v*'
jobs:
  goreleaser:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      -
        name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.4.0
      -
        name: Unshallow
        run: git fetch --prune --unshallow
      -
        name: Set up Go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v2
        with:
          go-version: 1.17
      -
        name: Import GPG key
        id: import_gpg
        uses: hashicorp/ghaction-import-gpg@v2.1.0
        env:
          # These secrets will need to be configured for the repository:
          GPG_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.GPG_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          PASSPHRASE: ${{ secrets.PASSPHRASE }}
      -
        name: Run GoReleaser
        uses: goreleaser/goreleaser-action@v2.8.0
        with:
          version: latest
          args: release --rm-dist
        env:
          GPG_FINGERPRINT: ${{ steps.import_gpg.outputs.fingerprint }}
          # GitHub sets this automatically
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```